# Dependency resolution problems with cmake installation

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, cmake

I want to install `cmake` in my system but i get the following error. i think version of libexpat1 library in my system is incompatible with the one libexpat1-dev needs. How can I install the required version?

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cmake : Depends: cmake-data (= 3.5.1-1ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libjsoncpp1 but it is not going to be installed
 libexpat1-dev : Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.0.1-7.2ubuntu1.4) but 2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: You can do as suggested and try `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo apt-get install -f cmake`? Thanks.

Comment: Also important to know which version of Ubuntu you are running. I just ran `sudo apt-get -s install cmake` on 16.4.02 without errors.

Comment: I am facing this issue in ubuntu 18.04.1